# Port Oracle encryption function to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, encryption, aes

I'm trying to port an Oracle function to Postgres. The purpose of this function is encrypt data using AES-256 algorithm. Since I'm no expert in either Oracle or cryptography I would highly appreciate all possible help. The goal is to get the same encrypted result both in Oracle and Postgres using the same data and key.

The Oracle function is

```
function encrypt(data varchar2, key raw) return raw as
begin
  return dbms_crypto.encrypt(
      utl_i18n.string_to_raw(data, 'AL32UTF8'),
      dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_AES256
      + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC
      + dbms_crypto.PAD_PKCS5,
      key
    );
end;
```

Comment: Please confirm exactly which distribution and version of Postgres you are working with. There are a number of possible responses here, depending on your answer.

Comment: Do you need this function to return **exactly** the same thing as the Oracle function (e.g. so that you can validate an encrypted password)?

Comment: The ported function should work in free version of PostgreSQL, preferable version 9.3 or later

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I had same issue.
Here is identical encryption/decryption from oracle/postgres using AES128
I have not (as yet) enjoyed success with 256 encryption but I haven't given up either.

```
    ORACLE  
    -----------------
      select RAWTOHEX ( DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt (
                                          src   => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('TEST', 'AL32UTF8'),
                                          typ   => 6+256+4096/* DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5   */,
                                          key   => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (RPAD ('1234', (128/8))))) val
      from dual;
      --4710C33D1568176FD6862FC58930B274
      
      select  UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (DBMS_CRYPTO.decrypt (
                                          src   => hextoraw('4710C33D1568176FD6862FC58930B274'),
                                          typ   => 6+256+4096/* DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5   */,
                                          key   => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (RPAD ('1234', (128/8)))), 'AL32UTF8') val
      from dual;
      --TEST
        
    POSTGRES  
    -----------------  
      select  upper(encode(encrypt('TEST', rpad('1234',128/8)::bytea, 'aes'),'HEX')) VAL;
      -- 4710C33D1568176FD6862FC58930B274 
       
       select convert_from(decrypt('\x4710C33D1568176FD6862FC58930B274',rpad('1234',128/8)::bytea,'aes'),'SQL_ASCII') VAL;
       --TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [`encrypt`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.8) function of the `pgcrypto` extension. It may not be a 100% replacement, but perhaps it is close enough.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of pgcrypto extension but I was not able to create a function similar as above with it, probably because of lack of knowledge of cryptography.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert in Postgres, but it appears that the Postgres DBMS_CRYPTO package is only included in the closed source Postgres EDB, not PostgreSQL, and that it only supports RAW, BLOB, and CLOB data types, not VARCHAR2. Also, it supports a different set of ciphers than Oracle, none being stronger than AES128. See here for details: https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/database-compatibility-for-oracle-developers-built-in-package-guide/12/Database_Compatibility_for_Oracle_Developers_Built-in_Package_Guide.1.16.html

In short, it doesn't look like you can do exactly what you're trying to (use DBMS_CRYPTO, that is). If you're using PostgreSQL, you'll need to look at some other alternative like pg_crypto. If you're considering EDB, then you'll need to switch data types and sacrifice some level of security to make the switch.

Comment: There is no `DBMS_CRYPTO` package in PostgreSQL, and indeed there are no packages at all.. You are talking about a closed-source fork of PostgreSQL.

Comment: The OP did not specify PostgreSQL, but rather Postgres; Postgres EDB Advanced Server appears to be alive and well, and does support DBMS_CRYPTO. It @tok would please confirm which version they are using, it would help clarify the appropriate answer for this post.

Comment: I'm sorry I was too inaccurate. I meant free version of Postgres, the PostgreSQL, and version number 9.3 or later.